# Tensorflow Wide & Deep Example Not Working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to get the [Wide & Deep](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html) tutorial working but the following line keeps giving me issues when copying and pasting the code from github and the website.

```
df_train["income_bracket"].apply(lambda x: ">50K" in x)).astype(int)
```

I get the below error

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

I am not too familar with lamda functions but I think it is making a dummy variable so I tried that using

```
for i in range(len(df_train)):
    if df_train.loc[i,'income_bracket']=='>50k':
        df_train.loc[i,LABEL_COLUMN] =1
    else:
        df_train.loc[i,LABEL_COLUMN] =0
```

But got the error

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got nan

How do I get this tutorial working?

EDIT:
first line of data and headers
[image]

Answer (score 2):

lambda function is quite useful and simple. It won't create dummy variables. 
I've noticed that you import the original data into a CSV file. Try not do that and just use the original downloading data that shown in tutorial code. I have successfully tried in this way. 
But I also got the same problem when I change to other data sets for training. So I still hope someone can solve this problem in a deeper way

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue of the data, or the code of TensorFlow. We have submit the issue about that in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4293

You can download the files manually and remove the broken lines. Then run with this command.

```
python ./wide_n_deep_tutorial.py --train_data /home/data/train_data --test_data /home/data/test_data
```